# d3 time series tick format; displaying formatted labels, but preserve underlying date in clicks

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've got a timeline that needs to display some counts for every hour in a day. The `x` data is something like `[10/01/2000 00:00, 10/01/2000 01:00, ...]`.  In the interest of keeping my x ticks legible, I'd like to drop the `10/01/2000` part of the string, *but* the data comes in as a full date, and I also need to keep that full date when I click the bar.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a momentjs helper to handle your dates/times.

```js
var formatDate = function(date, inputFormat, outputFormat) {

  console.log(moment(date, inputFormat).format(outputFormat));
  return moment(date, inputFormat).format(outputFormat);

};

formatDate('10/01/2000 01:00', 'dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm', 'hh:mm');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think d3.time.format is useful here. Hour Minute is used below.

```
var customTimeFormat = d3.time.format("%H:%M");   

var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([new Date(2000, 01, 10, 0), new Date(2000, 01, 10, 12)])
        .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickFormat(customTimeFormat);
```

For a SVG Title to show full data (Assumes you've given an ID of 'xaxis' to your axis)

```
 d3.select('#xaxis')
    .selectAll('.tick')
    .append("svg:title")
        .text(function(d, i) { return d });
```

For an onclick the below would be used, you could implement clickMe how you want. A simple alert to something nicer looking such as http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579

```
 d3.select('#xaxis')
    .selectAll('.tick')
    .on('click',clickMe)
```